# How can I mass assign across 2 models when importing a csv file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, nested-attributes, nested-resources

I can import a CSV file and create a new object (listing in this case) using the attributes from a single model.

I put this in the Listing model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

where address is an associated model (address has many listings, listing belongs to address).

I thought I'd then be able to mass assign attributes from the address model also when importing the CSV file but I get the error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: unit_number
```

where unit_number in one of the attributes in the address model (it's in attr accessible).

Comment: Can you update the question and put the models with its relationships and the attr_accessible code you wrote?

Comment: can you also provide the code that you use to do the assignment from CSV?

Comment: Do you want to create a new address while creating a listing?

Comment: oh, I see the code, you try to assign :unit_number to Listing instead of Address

Comment: basically I want to create a whole new item which takes attributes from the listing model and the address model. so my csv contains attributes of both models.  when I upload it I want to save the attributes in their respective models

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your Listing class definition change your import method:

```
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Listing.create!( :price => row[0], :status => row[1], 
                       :beds => row[2], :baths => row[3], 
                       :address_attributes => {:unit_number => row[4]} ) 
    end
end
```

Comment: @MichaeleRomano it will create the address record with only unit_number, all other fields will be blank. :)

Comment: @SybariteManoj, correct. @Michael Romano, just start from here and keep adding attributes from your CSV. E.g.  if you have 'city' in row[5] of your CSV, just change the address_attributes line to `:address_attributes => {:unit_number => row[4], :city => row[5]}` and so on, and so forth.