# Can't mass-assign protected attributes error - not able to import data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple csv import functionality and I am getting this error

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: First Name    Last Name   Email

I am very surprised this is happening since I do have attr_accessible for these fields. Here is my info.rb model code

```
attr_accessible :email, :fname, :lname

def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    Contact.create! row.to_hash
  end
end
```

My CSV is test.csv (the export is working fine, only the import of data is giving this error)

```
First Name  Last Name   Email
John    Smith   john@example.com
Janen   Smith   jane@example.com
```

Comment: what is the version of rails '4' ??

Answer (score 2):

You only have `attr_accessible` defined for `:email`, `:fname`, `:lname`.

Your csv contains `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Email` and they are different from `:email`, `:fname`, `:lname`.

So, you need to add the following to make it work:

```
attr_accessible :"First Name", :"Last Name", :Email
```

**Update:**

While this solution works, it does not look pretty!

On your second comment:

> Btw, right now, I have to keep the 1st row as fname,lname,email, is there anyway the user can uplaod file with - FirstName,LastName,Email which can be mapped to fname,lname,email

For this, the solution presented by @monangik is perfect!

Comment: Hi @vinodadhikary - well I changed the csv 1st row to fname,lname and email, still getting the same error "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: fname lname email"

Comment: @iCyborg, Could you try: `Contact.create! row.to_hash.symbolize_keys`

Comment: vinod, I got it, actually the file needs need to be comma separated, I was uploading it as tab separated :) Btw, right now, I have to keep the 1st row as fname,lname,email, is there anyway the user can uplaod file with - FirstName,LastName,Email which can be mapped to fname,lname,email ?

Comment: @iCyborg, you could just pass in the `without_protection` option when doing this.  Something like `Contact.create(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys, without_protection: true)`, give that a try and post back if that does not help.

Comment: Thanks, I will reply in 1-2 hours as I am leaving right now, but will surely check the code once I am back

Comment: Please find a better alternative to this: `attr_accessible :"First Name", :"Last Name", :Email`

Comment: @DamienRoche, I'm unsure if you got a chance to read all the comments.  I agree that the initial solution I presented does not look nice but my intention was to so a method to symbolize strings with spaces on them.  May I request your suggestion when you say "better alternative to this..."

Comment: Hi @vinodadhikary, I'd say changing the input parameters is a better alternative than accepting bad parameter naming, as shown in monangik's answer. I agree on symbolize_keys, probably best solution out of all of them.

Comment: @DamienRoche, Yes the `symbolize_keys` would have been much nicer.  Anyway, I've updated my answer redirecting users to see monangik's answer as I suppose this conversation started because I did not maintain the updates from comments in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147777/how-can-i-mass-assign-across-2-models-when-importing-a-csv-file). This might solve your problem.

```
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Contact.create!( :fname => row[0], 
                       :lname => row[1], 
                       :email => row[2] 
                      ) 
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @monangik, will come back in few hours and try it